# I can't write object literal notation in Dev Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I get error when i write this:

```
{a:1, b:2}
```

but not when i just write this

```
{a:1}
```

I've tried in Firefox and chrome both give errors.

There is no error if i Assign it to a variable.

**Has it been the case always?, Why there is error. There is no error is nodejs in commandline.**

*I discovered error once i copy pasted the json code to better explore it. Then did experiments.. (this has to be something new)*

Comment: Just curious, why would you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: Brackets also represent [statement blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). Start-of-the-line vs. as an Expression later in a Statement is how the two are distinguished.

Comment: i wanted to expand minified json  and explore it

Comment: Regarding Node.js' REPL, it's defined to recognize and wrap such input in [grouping operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) so they're no longer parsed as statements at the start of the line.

Comment: Why don't you do `myvar = {a:1}`? Then play around with your myvar.

Comment: i can, but it doesn't explained why previous wasn't working

Comment: [Please use the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+object+literal+console). *"Has it been the case always"* Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{ /* ... */ }` is a [block statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1).

If you want it to be parsed as an [object initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), you must use it in a place where an expression is expected.

Some examples:

```js
{} + ''; // `0`, parsed as block
'' + {}; // `"[object Object]"`, parsed as expression
{} * 1; // Error, parsed as block
1 * {}; // `NaN`, parsed as expression
```

A way to parse it as an expression and get the resulting object as the result is enclosing it inside parentheses:

```js
({ /* ... */ })
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the object in parenthesis, like this:

`({a:1, b:2})`

The reason is that JavaScript uses curly brackets for a number of different things, such as if-statements, for-loops, and in your case, object declarations.

When you're not doing any sort of assignment, in other words, setting it equal to a variable, then the curly brackets mean something different by default.

To insist that JavaScript treat these floating curly brackets as Object literal notation, you must wrap the curly brackets in parenthesis.

Comment: You should explain why

Answer (score 1):

> *(this has to be something new)*

Nope. This:

```
{a:1}
```

...is not treated as an object literal either. You can see that when you enter it into the console, because the console comes back with `1`, *not* with an object. It is interpreted as the beginning of a block statement, followed by the [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) `a:`, followed by the expression `1`, then the end of the block.

With that in mind, you can see that this:

```
{a:1, b:2}
```

...is interpreted as the beginning of a block statement, the *label* `a:`, then the expression `1, b` followed by an unexpected `:`.

This will be the case whether in the browser console or in a script in an html page. To have the browser treat the whole thing as an expression just wrap it in parentheses:

```
({a:1, b:2})
```